# Uniqueness of _id column in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-query

I want to use custom _id generation. The following is how I am using it. Please guide for anticipated problems.

### Current Implementation

I have a collection in mongo with multiple documents nesting. For every document I insert at a particular level it has a unique _id. However, at different levels the _id may repeat itself. The _id may repeat itself for another collection too.

My current data set is < 300 documents with 2 level of nesting.
1. Would I have problems with large datasets?
2. Sharding problems?
3. Any thing else?

Answer (score 0):

OK, in short, the answer is: yes, you are likely to encounter challenges and it would not be recommended unless you are attempting to solve an issue that the default is unable to.

The long answer requires a short intro into how mongoid implements _id.

See here:

```
  field(
        :_id,
        default: ->{ BSON::ObjectId.new },
        pre_processed: true,
        type: BSON::ObjectId
      )
```

And secondly that mongoid deals with identity as the combination of class & id:

```
    def identity
      [ self.class, self._id ]
    end
```

Now, BSON::ObjectId.new (spec for BSON [here](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification)) creates a 12 byte value consisting of a 4-byte timestamp (0..3), a 3-byte machine id (4..6), a 2-byte process id (7..8), and a 3-byte counter (9..11).

```
> BSON::ObjectId.new.to_bson.length
=> 12
```

It records the time is was generated, which is quite handy to know:

```
> BSON::ObjectId.new.generation_time
=> 2016-05-24 05:47:20 UTC
```

The rationale behind using a BSON::ObjectId as _id is the indexable benefits. As it is time based, finding a value based on time is fast in the index. It is also unique in both concurrency threads (different processes, by different machines), and it's own (hence the inc counter for operations within the same second on the same process). This only needs to be unique within a collection due to identity being a combination of class & _id.

**In answer to your question**

From what you have written, it is assumed that you are embedding documents within each other. As embedded documents can only be searched from the actual document, and that embedded documents have their own classes then the _id only needs to be unique within that class.

Example:

```
class A
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :b
  embeds_many :c, class_name: 'B'
end 

class B
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :a
end

>obj = A.create
=> #<A _id: 5743f10b0da757b22a1cfa69, >

> obj.b << B.new
=> [#<B _id: 5743f12f0da757b22a1cfa6a, >]

> obj.as_document
=> {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5743f10b0da757b22a1cfa69'), "b"=>[{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5743f12f0da757b22a1cfa6a')}]}

> A.find_by('b._id' => BSON::ObjectId('5743f12f0da757b22a1cfa6a'))
=> #<A _id: 5743f10b0da757b22a1cfa69, >

>obj.c << B.new
=> [#<B _id: 5743f2590da757b22a1cfa6b, >]

> obj.as_document
=> {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5743f10b0da757b22a1cfa69'), "b"=>[{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5743f12f0da757b22a1cfa6a')}], "c"=>[{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5743f2590da757b22a1cfa6b')}]}
```

As you can see from the above, you can search, store and find robustly across embedded documents using the mongoid implementation of _id. As the BSON::ObjectId is unique to the time even in embedded documents, then we (the community) would need information on your rationale for a custom _id as you may be attempting to solve a problem already solved by the default implementation. Hopefully the above gives you an insight into the mechanics to guide your decision making.

Comment: Thanks, it's a very comprehensive answer. However to answer your question, there are no specifics on why it is like this.